# XSL Sorting With Sitecore

Tags: xslt, sitecore

I'm not very familiar with xsl, so I'm sort of stumbling my way though this.

My xsl file is building a menu. I am trying to sort the menu items by the value in menu title field in Sitecore. When I run the code, it does not sort. It just writes out each menu item four times.

Can anyone shed some light on what I am missing?

```
<xsl:template name="show-title">
    <xsl:param name="root" />
    <xsl:for-each select="$sc_currentitem/item">
        <xsl:sort select="sc:fld('menu title',.)" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="sc:fld('menu title',$root)!=''">
                <sc:text field="menu title" select="$root" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$root/@name" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

EDIT: Below is the data that the code above is generating
Example Output:

- 03/05/201203/05/201203/05/201203/05/2012
- 03/01/201203/01/201203/01/201203/01/2012
- 03/08/201203/08/201203/08/201203/08/2012
- 03/02/201203/02/201203/02/201203/02/2012
- 03/07/201203/07/201203/07/201203/07/2012

I am trying to get it to generate the following:

- 03/01/2012
- 03/02/2012
- 03/05/2012
- 03/07/2012
- 03/08/2012

Thanks!

Comment: Sample input xml and also the context from which this template is being called would really help

Comment: This is part of my problem. I'm not really sure what I'm dealing with. I'm basically just trying to figure out how to sort the dates ('menu title'). When I tried adding sc_currentitem/item to the for-each tag, it causesd the data to appear multiple times for each menu item. The date should only be appearing once and not repeating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to read menu title field from the wrong node. You should be reading it from context node --> **.** <--

Try this

```
<xsl:template name="show-title">
    <xsl:param name="root" />
    <xsl:for-each select="$sc_currentitem/item">
        <xsl:sort select="sc:fld('menu title',.)" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="sc:fld('menu title',$root)!=''">
                <sc:text field="menu title" select="." />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="./@name" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess as you don't really supply enough information for anyone to do more than guess but....

Within your for-each you are referring to $root e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="$root/@name" />`

I am guessing that the $root parameter contains a list of some kind and that you should be selecting just part of this list based on some value from the current for-each context